BloC: Widget is not updating after a new state is emitted
On my "ProductScreen" I have a custom TextFiled which is declared like this
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: Dimensions.m),
  child: AppMoneyField(
    title: "Value",
    initialValue: state.cost,
    isMandatory: true,
    onTextChange: (value) {
      context.read<AddPositionBloc>().add(ChangeCostEvent(double.tryParse(value)));
    })),

On the initState of AppMoneyField I defined how to handle initialValue
  @override
  void initState() {
    controller = TextEditingController(
        text: widget.initialValue != null
            ? NumberFormat(".##").format(widget.initialValue)
            : "");
    super.initState();
  }

Initially state.cost is null, so the textfield is empty. Then after the data are fetched, the new state comes in. My problem is that when the new state comes, it triggers a UI rebuild since I am using a BlocBuilder, but the initState in AppMoneyField is not called, only the build method is called, so the TextField doesn't update.
Is is normal that initState is not called? How should I do it then?

can you include the state class

Found how to do it, I had to call didUpdateWidget
  void initController() {
    controller = TextEditingController(
        text: widget.initialValue != null
            ? NumberFormat(".##").format(widget.initialValue)
            : "");
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initController();
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(AppMoneyField oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    initController();
  }

